# Казнить нельзя помиловать

Tags: фразеология, пунктуация

Это выражение, которое все наши школьные учителя использовали как аргумент в пользу необходимости тщательного изучения пунктуации, за столько лет использования в таком качестве стало атрибутом языка зануд. Любители пренебрегать нормами языка давно выработали к нему иммунитет и эффектностью амфиболии, заключенной в нем, уже не впечатляются. Какие еще примеры важности пунктуации для понимания смысла сказанного можно предложить? Я часто встречаю в литературе предложения, смысл которых меняется при изменении пунктуационного оформления, но составить из них коллекцию я не потрудилась не в последнюю очередь потому, что изменение смысла в них было недостаточно радикальным, чтобы они могли стать достойной альтернативой вышеозначенному фразеологизму. Но может быть, кто-то этим коллекционированием занимался. Было бы интересно обсудить эту тему здесь.

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Вроде бы нужную вам фразу нашёл, хотя из-за склонений и спряжений это не так-то и просто.

Answer (score 7):

Существует предание о некоем завещателе, в чьем (прошу прощения за тавтологию)завещании было написано, что наследники должны поставить *статую золотую пику держащую.* Что должно быть из золота? Статуя? Пика? Наследники сэкономили. Прочитали так, как им выгодно.

Примеры, подобные этому или приведенному Вами, можно придумывать самому.

Comment: Дело в том, что подобные примеры, хотя их можно придумывать самому, имеют тот недостаток, что не допускают, как правило, больше двух возможных трактовок. Бывают более сложные случаи вроде английского «James while John had had had had had had had had had had had a better effect on the teacher», где без знаков препинания вообще невозможно ничего понять. Англичане, к слову, в этом отношении оказались изобретательнее нас.

Comment: >James while John had had had had had had had had had had had a better effect on the teacher  
  
Перебор, однако. Как знаки не ставь, грамматика нарушена. 
Видел несколько искуственную английскую фразу с семью "that" подряд, но там просто игра на разных значениях. Типа "косил косой косой косой".

Answer (score 5):

Классику привела Ларf, а вообще такие фразы довольно однообразны:  вот, например,приписывается   Петру I:"Строить нельзя сносить".

Или:"Снести нельзя облагородить".
"Уйти нельзя остаться"."Аборт нельзя рожать".

Ставить или не ставить запятую:"С одной стороны() мясо готово".

"Этой дорогой мы дойдём ()скорее всего"

Comment: Действительно, однообразны. Они все аналогичны этому пресловутому "Казнить - помиловать". Меня интересуют более сложные пунктуационные схемы, не афористические.

Answer (score 3):

Мне бы было бы интересней услышать на уроке фразы типа "*Ты школьник - Ты - школьник*" и сравнить отличия, но возможно это уже для более взрослых детей. Из классиков могу вспомнить Пушкина.

> Довольно, стыдно мне
> Пред гордою полячкой унижаться...

Которая без запятой, превращается в такое манерное *Знаете ли, но мне довольно стыдно унижаться перед гордой полячкой*.

Или из Алексея Толстого:

> Шибанов   молчал . Из пронзенной ноги
>    Кровь алым струилася током.

Убери точку в первой строчке и перед нами картина из фильма ужасов: прнзённая нага, а оттуда выглядывает лицо зловеще молчащего Шибанова.

---

Дополнение. Кажется смог придумать фразу, где в зависимости от пунктуации возможно более двух толкований.

**С этой стороны мне показался месье с другой мадам.**
Без знаков препинания смысл фразы в том, что с одной из сторон появился месье с какой-то другой мадам.

*С этой стороны мне показался месье, с другой - мадам.*
Здесь месье и мадам идут уже не вместе, а с разных сторон.

*С этой стороны - мне показался месье, с другой - мадам.*
А тут вообще неясно кто перед нами, месье или мадам.

Последний вариант немного корявый, но вроде в пределах нормы.

Comment: Спасибо, но меня интересуют все-таки знаки препинания внутри предложения: чтобы поставить точку в конце, долго и упорно изучать правила пунктуации не требуется.

Comment: @Inkognito, в дидактических целях точку вполне можно заменить запятой.

Comment: ...А "молчал" на "выглядывал" - и ужасы можно будет смотреть прямо у нас на форуме))).

Comment: Что-то между вторым и третьим предложением не вижу разницы, кроме интонационного тире.

Comment: @Ларf, Если заменить синонимами, третья фраза должна звучать как: *С этой стороны - мне показался мужчиной,  с другой - женщиной*.

Answer (score 2):

*Казнить нельзя помиловать* по эмоциональному воздействию сильнее всех других приведённых вариантов, потому что здесь от запятой зависит жизнь человека.  Поэтому и до школьников доходит быстрее, поэтому и упорно живёт. 
А ещё мне понравилась фраза из ответа Ларf про золотую пику и статую. Это тоже школьникам близко и понятно.